# How Do I remove LXDE?

Tags: desktop-environments, purge

I tried LXDE and I really don't like it so I would like to get rid of it. I installed it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

and tried to remove it by typing

```
sudo apt-get purge lxde && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But the LXDE option is still in LightDM's desktop menu.
Can anybody tell me how to remove it from LightDM's menu?

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge lxde*

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot.

This should be it.

Comment: It is not running. I click onit and then log in then it just directs me to the login screen again. I want to get rid of it from the list too.

Comment: Try removing the `lxde-common` package as well - that's the one that provides the LXDE.desktop file, I think

Comment: No. It's still there.

Comment: try now re-edited answer. That will delete all LXDE belongings.

Comment: Is there a way to remove LXDE safely *after* installing LXqt?